# Facebook get if user share a url

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I need to know if a user has shared a url.

In which table can I find the url shared by a user?

```
    $query = 'SELECT url FROM  Table  WHERE user_id = '.$userId.' AND url='."'".$url."'";
    $response = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => $query));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`stream`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) table, check whether the posts have the value `80` for the `type` field:

> **type** *int32*
>
> - 80 - Link posted